# How to add a bot to a Telegram Group?

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I've been trying to add a bot to my Telegram group in Android Device but I am not able to do so. I tried @bot_name, /bot_name, but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to add a bot to the group or should I create a new bot using Telegram API (not bot API) so that I can add the contact number to the group?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Edit:** now there is yet an easier way to do this - when creating your group, just mention the full bot name (eg. @UniversalAgent1Bot) and it will list it as you type. Then you can just tap on it to add it.

**Old answer:**

1. Create a new group from the menu. Don't add any bots yet
2. Find the bot (for instance you can go to Contacts and search for it)
3. Tap to open
4. Tap the bot name on the top bar. Your page becomes like this:
   [image: Telegram bot settings]
5. Now, tap the triple ... and you will get the Add to Group button:
   [image: Adding the bot]
6. Now select your group and add the bot - and confirm the addition

Comment: This was by far the easiest way. But please make those screenshot inline. Thanks.

Comment: The bot also needs to be allowed to be assigned in bots. See the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37339365/5731101

Answer (score 39):

You have to use [@BotFather](https://telegram.me/BotFather), send it command: /setjoingroups
There will be dialog like this:

> YOU: /setjoingroups
>
> BotFather: Choose a bot to change group membership
>   settings.
>
> YOU: @YourBot
>
> BotFather: 'Enable' - bot can be added to groups. 'Disable' - block
>   group invitations, the bot can't be added to groups. Current status
>   is: DISABLED
>
> YOU: Enable
>
> BotFather: Success! The new status is: ENABLED.

After this you will see button "Add to Group" in your bot's profile.

Answer (score 6):

Another way :

change BOT_USER_NAME before use

```
https://telegram.me/BOT_USER_NAME?startgroup=true
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the 2 steps worked:

1. Added bot to a group as a regular member
2. **Made Bot an admin.**

The second step was needed to let Bot respond and sent messages to Group chat.

The response `event.postData.contents` looked like this:

```
{
   "ok":true,
   "result":{
      "message_id":31,
      "from":{
         "id":1234567890,
         "is_bot":true,
         "first_name":"bot for custom alerts",
         "username":"mybotname1_bot"
      },
      "chat":{
         "id":-1234567890,
         "title":"group name",
         "type":"group",
         "all_members_are_administrators":true
      },
      "date":1624860599,
      "text":"hi"
   }
}
```

I needed to receive the chat id (negative number from response) to send messages to the group by Bot.

Comment: It is worth highlighting here, that if your bot only listens to commands there is no requirement for admin. Admin is only needed for reading normal messages.