# Allow bot to access Telegram Group messages

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

One step further than [How to add a bot to a Telegram Group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338101/) --

How to add a bot to a Telegram Group as admin?

I've added my bot to *my* Telegram Group, but see that it

> has no access to messages

I heard the bot need to be admin to access to messages. True? If so, how? Else, how to have my bot access to group messages?

Comment: Use set privacy in bot father

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You have to use the @BotFather bot to set the Group Privacy off. This let the bot to access all the group messages.

By default, `Group Privacy` is `enabled` for bots. This setting has to be changed used the @BotFather bot >> Bot Settings >> Group Privacy >> Turn off

Please note that this change is not propagated automatically, so in case the bot is already in a group before turning off privacy mode, it will **remain** as it was before. To apply the changes, the bot should be removed and added again to the group(s). Alternatively, you can stop the bot and start again from within the group: Group Details -> Member Details -> Options -> Stop Bot and then Group Details -> Member Details -> Options -> Start bot.

Comment: Updated answer, check if your problem is solved with that, regards.